# Mongoose: TypeError: Invalid value for schema path `guildId.type`, got value "undefined"

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js, schema

I got this error but I don't know what I have done wrong.

My code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const GuildConfigSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  guildId: {
    type: mongoose.SchemaType.String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  prefix: {
    type: mongoose.SchemaType.String,
    required: true,
    default: 'b!',
  },
  defaultRole: {
    type: mongoose.SchemaType.String,
    required: false,
  },
  memberLogChannel: {
    type: mongoose.SchemaType.String,
    required: false,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('GuildConfig', GuildConfigSchema);
```

And my guild create event where I am setting the values of the database:

```
// https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildCreate
const BaseEvent = require('../utils/structures/BaseEvent');
const GuildConfig = require('../database/schemas/GuildConfig');
module.exports = class GuildCreateEvent extends BaseEvent {
  constructor() {
    super('guildCreate');
  }

  async run(client, guild) {
    try {
      const guildConfig = await GuildConfig.create({
        guildId: guild.id,
      });
      console.log('Successfully joined server!');
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
}
```

My error:

```
TypeError: Invalid value for schema path `guildId.type`, got value "undefined"
```

Does anyone see what I've done wrong?

Comment: can you show the code where you're setting the values?

Comment: I updated it in the question

Comment: Have you tried using a `console.log(...)` statement with `guild`? Is `guild.id` actually defined?

Answer (score 0):

explicitly export GuildConfigSchema
`module.exports.GuildConfigSchema = GuildConfigSchema;`

and use destructuring where the schema is required.
`const { GuildConfigSchema } = require("path to schema file");`

Comment: Can you explain how it would solve OP's problem?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: if you assign a type to some schema you need to import it to that module you are using. in the above code, it looks like he is not exporting the GuildConfigSchema  he only exports the schema model